# mysql query to get unique value from one column

Tags: database, mysql

i have a table named locations of which i want to select and get values in such a way that it should select only distinct values from a column but select all other values .

table name: locations
column names 1: country values : America, India, India, India
column names 2: state/Province : Newyork, Punjab, Karnataka, kerala

when i select i should get India only once and all the three states  listed under India . is ther any way..??? sombody please help

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
SELECT country, GROUP_CONCAT(state SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM locations
GROUP BY country
```

But this sort of thing is often best done in the presentation layer.

Comment: What do you mean by 'array format'? MySQL doesn't have arrays. I think you shouldn't be formatting of data for presentation in the database. You should do it in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

You want it **displayed** in that order, not **selected**?

In this case you have to add a condition inside of your loop to check a country and print ot out only if it was changed.